# What exactly is warning C4718 (of Visual Studio)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, recursion, compiler-warnings

[msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztya8zs5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

text here:

> 'function call' : recursive call has no side effects, deleting
>  A
>   function contains a recursive call, but otherwise has no side effects.
>   A call to this function is being deleted. The correctness of the
>   program is not affected, but the behavior is. Whereas leaving the call
>   in could result in a runtime stack overflow exception, deleting the
>   call removes that possibility.

The code causing this warning is:

```
template<class Key, class Value>
void Map<Key, Value>::Clear(NodeType* pNode)
{
    ((Key*) (pNode->m_key))->~Key();
    ((Value*) (pNode->m_item))->~Value();

    NodeType* pL = pNode->GetLeftChild();
    NodeType* pR = pNode->GetRightChild();
    if (pL != &m_dummy)
    {
        Clear(pL);
    }
    if (pR != &m_dummy)
    {
        Clear(pR);
    }
}
```

and 1 more point: this warning only happens in release build (/Ox)

What is this warning? Thanks!

Comment: Template code I assume, `Key` and `Value` are template parameters?

Comment: Oh yes! template code, sorry for unclear text provided! i'll edit now!

Comment: Any reason why there's a need for a cast on the first two lines? I can't imagine any good reason. (If they're `void*`, that's not a good reason.)

Comment: they are `char` arrays, it's because `m_key` and `m_item` are for placement new. Done like `new (pNode->m_key) Key(key)` in another function.

Comment: the declaration of them are like `uint8 m_key[sizeof(Key)]` and `uint8 m_item[sizeof(Value)];`

Comment: If you already know the type, why not `Key m_key` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll bet it occurs when `~Key` and `~Value` are no-ops. The compiler will notice that there is literally nothing else that this function tries to do, so it entirely eliminates this function.

Answer (score 4):

For starters, the warning only happens in a release build because it's the result of an optimization, and the optimizer only runs during release builds.

The optimizer is allowed to restructure or eliminate code, including recursive calls, if it can prove that that will not change the program behavior.  <strike>There is probably some data-dependent path where one or both calls to Clear() for the left and right nodes would have no effect.</strike>

Edit: As @MSalters points out, it is more likely that the destructors for Key and Value are no-ops -- as they would be if Key and Value are both plain-old-data structures or simple types, since the destructors are the only side-effect possible from the function as written.

Edit 2: instead of using placement new, why not use the : initializer?

```
template struct Map<typename Key, typename Value> {
    Key key;
    Value value;

    Map(Key k, Value v) : key(k), value(v) {}
}
```

Comment: +1 to @MSalters below, that's probably exactly why the optimizer sees no side effect -- no effect of the explicit destructor calls.

Also - unless you really really need to - you should avoid calling destructors explicitly like that.  There's almost always a better (cleaner, more maintainable, more portable...) way to do something.  In this case I'd suggest templates, though if you need to implement binary trees like this for a class or something, then go for it.

Comment: @jmstoker I suspect this is the style where instead of using NULL to show a terminal leaf, there is a sentinel value (they're calling it dummy, but I prefer sentinel) -- usually I see this in doubly linked lists, but there's no reason it can't work with a binary tree.

If that's the case, then the recursion will terminate assuming the tree is acyclic..

Comment: Hi: I explicitly call dtor because it's a matter of placement new

Comment: Rather than using placement new on Key and Value in your Map, can't you define the Map with explicit values and use the : initializer syntax (see edit above)